# How would I show the bottomTabNavigator in all drawerNavigators?

Tags: react-native

This is my setup, using **react-navigation 4**:

```
**//Stack Navigators**
const Stack1 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Screen1: Screen1,
    Screen2: Screen2
  }
);

const Stack2 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Screen3: Screen3,
    Screen4: Screen4
  }
);

const Stack3 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Screen5: Screen5,
    Screen6: Screen6
  }
);

**//Tab Navigator**
const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    1: {
      screen: Stack1,
    },
    2: {
      screen: Stack2,
    }
  }
);

**//DrawerNavigator**
const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Nav: {
      screen: TabNav,
    },

    SecondDrawerLink: {
      screen: Stack3,
    },
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

My Tabs (TabNav) are only showing in "Nav" Drawer but not in the "SecondDrawerLink" Drawer. Which makes sense, because I only add "TabNav" to the "Nav" Drawer. The problem is, I can't wrap my head around how I would show my "TabNav" in all of my other DrawerLinks.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would try inserting the pages from `Stack3` into the `Stack1` and `Stack2`. And from the `SecondDrawerLink` trigger a custom call, which navigates to the `Screen5` for instance.

This way your stack from either `Stack1` or `Stack2` will accept the special Drawer's command, and you'll still be able to go back to the screen you were before triggering the `SecondDrawerLink`.

Comment: Thanks, this could actually be a work-around, if there's actually no official solution for it. But how would the custom call look like? Could you give an example. Thanks.

Comment: To trigger custom functions it's recommended that you have a custom Drawer component, then it's way more flexible what you can do with the options inside it. The react-navigation team inserted a snipped on their documentation that could be very useful for your scenario: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/ . In this screen search for "function CustomDrawerContent(props)", unfortunately the link for the working snipped is too long and I can't paste as a comment